# How make loading font in iframe from Microsoft Power BI?

Tags: html, css, iframe, fonts, powerbi

I wrote my custom font in JSON theme's file and made report in iframe.
There are span and iframe tags in my test website. My span see custom font and show it correctly, but, unfortunately iframe no.

My DevTools in Chrome show that span and iframe's text use my custom font.

in index.css i have next font-face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'XXSansUI-Regular';
  src: url('./fonts/XXSansUI-Regular.eot');
  src: url('./fonts/XXSansUI-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('./fonts/XXSansUI-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('./fonts/XXSansUI-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
      url('./fonts/XXSansUI-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: auto;
}
```

I tried to use preload attribute for link tag and also change font-display, but it isnt working ;(